# Completeness of real closed fields within ZFC

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, model-theory, proof-theory, incompleteness

Tarski proved that the theory of real closed fields (RCF) is complete. But does this theory stay complete when interpreted within ZFC? We know that ZFC can't be complete because it can interpret arithmetic. My guess is that RCF within ZFC becomes incomplete since we can define a predicate which picks out the set-theoretic natural numbers among the set-theoretic real numbers. According to Peter Smith, this is $\textsf{Nat}()$ predicate is essential to showing that a theory is incomplete (or has he puts it, *incompleteable*).

More formally, let $T$ be a complete theory within some language $L_T$ and let $S$ be a theory within some langauge $L_S$ which can interpret arithmetic. Suppose we can map every unique element of $T$'s domain to a unique element of $S$'s domain and that every function symbol, constant symbol, relation symbol, and quantifier (to pick out only the S-elements which correspond to T-elements) in $L_T$ can be defined as some wff of $L_S$ . Then is $S$ negation complete w.r.t to sentences constructed from these wffs?

If my guess is correct, can someone provide an example of a statement within RCF for which it and its negation are not provable when interpreted in ZFC? Originally I was thinking the continuum hypothesis but on second thought this requires more than what the language of RCF can talk about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your guess is **incorrect**: $\mathsf{RCF}$ remains complete even when we restrict to what $\mathsf{ZFC}$ itself can prove. To make this precise:

> For every sentence $\sigma$ in the language of $\mathsf{RCF}$, either $\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash(\mathsf{RCF}\vdash\sigma)$ or $\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash(\mathsf{RCF}\vdash\neg\sigma)$. Moreover, this statement itself is provable inside $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

This doesn't immediately follow from the *statement* of Tarski's theorem, but it does follow from the *proof*: the proof that $\mathsf{RCF}$ is complete is entirely constructive, giving a specific algorithm for checking whether or not a sentence is a theorem of $\mathsf{RCF}$, and $\mathsf{ZFC}$ can prove that this algorithm is correct and always terminates.

---

To see that the OP (and the answer above) is not actually trivial, consider the case of true arithmetic $\mathsf{TA}$. This is definable in set theory, and so the following question makes sense:

> "Is it the case that, for every sentence $\varphi$ in the language of arithmetic, either $\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash(\mathsf{TA}\vdash\varphi)$ or $\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash(\mathsf{TA}\vdash\neg\varphi)$ hold?"

But this time, in contrast with the $\mathsf{RCF}$ example, the answer is negative: if we take $\varphi$ to be the Rosser sentence for $\mathsf{ZFC}$, then (unless $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is inconsistent of course!) $\mathsf{ZFC}$ cannot tell whether $\varphi$ is true (remember that "provable from $\mathsf{TA}$" is synonymous with "true," literally by definition, for sentences of arithmetic).

Comment: It's not clear that this is what the OP meant by "RCF within ZFC". The second paragraph makes it sound like they're talking about an interpretation of theories, as opposed to an internalization (e.g. the standard one being the interpretation of RCF in ZFC by the construction of the reals as dedekind cuts). Of course, with this reading the question is trivial, since part of the definition of "interpretation" is that ZFC proves the translation of every theorem of RCF. So you answered a better question.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I am confused as to what difference there is between $\textit{interpretation}$ and $\textit{internalization}$, as you go on to explain the latter in terms of the former.

Comment: @ngc1300 My comment could have been more clear. The Dedekind cuts construction gives an interpretation of RCF in ZFC. In particular, every sentence in the language of fields translates to a sentence in the language of set theory (about Dedekind cuts), and ZFC proves all of the translations of consequences of RCF - if it didn't, it wouldn't count as an interpretation! By internalization, I mean a construction (e.g. by Gödel coding) that codes every sentence in the language of fields as a mathematical object (e.g. a number). This is what Noah's answer refers to.